# Could not open the folder, obviously it's there

Tags: python, jupyter-lab

[image]

I have a dataset folder but cannot get access in jupyter lab.
I try to get access to the images inside the folder but failed.
And then I try to use `cd` and `ls` to find the folder but it's not there.
Obviously it's inside the root dir and it's on in the left part of the image.

Any advice or thoughts?

Comment: Have you actually tried opening the folder elsewhere?

Comment: It can be open in the Finder and left side of the screen shot you can see 'dataset' folder locate at the same root dir as dimages and cpp folder.

Comment: try `ls -a` to see if its hidden

Comment: ls -a does not show as well...

Comment: Try `!pwd` to see the working directory.